# Why openerp one2one type is deprecated after version 5?

Tags: odoo

I create a custom module and I want add a one2one relationship between a person and a country. But when I use one2one type, there 's an error, I google it and I've known the one2one type is deprecated after version 5. I just want to know why OE made the one2one type deprecated ?